# Dynamic calculation of a TextView that is linked to a seris of buttons

Tags: java, javascript, android, textview

I'm trying to [create this flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD3eo.jpg) on an application I'm building. I am having a little bit of trouble getting the TextView to be friendly with any kind of formula/conditions. Any suggestions on how I can get the TextView to output the result dynamically through my text watchers? Thanks in advance!

Text Views

```
    //------------------DISPLAY-----------------\\
    netsale = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.netsale_input);

    //--------------WAIT ASSISTANT--------------\\
    waMain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_wa_main);
    waSplit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_wa_split);
```

Clear Button

```
public void clr_Clicked(View sender){
        netsale.setText("0");
        isempty=true;
    }
```

Number Pad

```
static boolean isempty=true;
public void num_Clicked(View sender){   
    Button bt=(Button)sender;
    if(netsale.getText().length()>5)return;
    if(isempty)
        {
            if(bt.getText().toString().equals("0"))return;
            netsale.setText(bt.getText());
            isempty=false;
        }
    else
        {
            netsale.append(bt.getText());
        }
}
```

Text Watchers

```
 private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {    

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button, lets say "7", you should append that value to the TextView by utilizing `setText(CharSequence);`

So at first if your TextView is blank (""), when you click the 7, it should result in your TextView showing "7"